# Windows telnet client that does carriage return on LFs

Tags: windows

I have a customized box sending mostly LFs for line breaks (sometimes CRLFs too).

I wish to connect to it from a Windows box using telnet, but it seems it won't do the carriage returns where lines end with LF only.

I have tried PuTTY, HyperTerminal and the Command Prompt telnet client...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PuTTY, have you tried activating the setting "Implicit CR in every LF" (it's under Terminal)?

Answer (score 0):

[Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) is a great open-source tool which can be used to replace telnet in some cases.

Don't know if a windows version exists out there, but it could be worth compiling it !

To telnet a host :

```
$ nc host port
```

To get the html of a webpage :

```
$ echo "GET /" | nc host 80
```

Quick and dirty Syslog server :

```
# nc -l -u -p 514
```

It will print on screen what was sent to the server.

Comment: There is a version precompiled for windows [here](http://www.rodneybeede.com/Compile_Netcat_on_Windows_using_MinGW.html), but it might be worth mentioning that it isn't a full telnet client: a real telnet client has other features. That being said, netcat is a wonderful tool that I've used in many situations.